# How can I exit from vi using a shell script?

Tags: scripting, vi

I have an existing script `test.sh` which does some operations and then finally opens a file in vi. I cannot make any changes to this existing script. When I run the first script it opens a text file in vi. Now I have another script where I run the existing script `test.sh`. It opens a file in vi. How do I `:wq` from inside the script? Is it even possible?

Comment: Does the script open Vi into an interactive editing session? Does the script read its own standard input from anywhere?

Comment: The script open VI in command mode (where you press i and then edit the file). The script reads its own standard input.

Comment: Your script calls a script that you can't edit, and it's that second script that calls vi?!!

Comment: @JeffSchaller the first script does certain operations and then finally opens up a file in text mode where I am supposed to do some manual actions and save the file. I am trying to automate this part. In order to proceed further, I need to exit VI first thing.

Comment: How would you know when the user was done editing? Maybe ed or ex or sed are better ways to edit, non-interactively?

Comment: It sound like you may want to have an interactive and a non-interactive version of that script, or possibly two different scripts all-together.

Comment: If it was vim you could "vim --servername server --remote-send ':wqa!<CR>'" depending how the first script launched... (see :h clientserver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to simulate communication with a program which expects a terminal, look for the `expect` program which is made for that, it adds commands to `tcl` to allow controlling another program and communicating with it through a pseudo-terminal.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? I am not familiar with expect.

Comment: Sorry, I last used it some years ago and would have to digg into its manual to be able to provide the simplest example.

Comment: Expect worked good. It is a a bit slow though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the [`ex` editor](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/unixnut/ch09_01.htm), which is the foundation upon which `vi` serves as the interactive visual editor.

`ex` can easily edit files non-interactively, which is perfect for scripts.

I was going to make a longer answer, but the **vi stackexchange** already has a good one, at https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/788/how-to-edit-files-non-interactively-e-g-in-pipeline.